# Why is it OK to initialize global variable with result from inline assembly code?

Tags: c++, inline-assembly

Consider this code which would compile on PIC32 (source: openscope-mz)

```
static  uint32_t    tSLoop              = ReadCoreTimer();

static inline uint32_t ReadCoreTimer(void)
{
    uint32_t coreTimerCount;
    __asm__ __volatile__("mfc0 %0,$9" : "=r" (coreTimerCount));
    return(coreTimerCount);
}
```

Please explain why this is valid C code.

Comment: Since inline assembly is implementation-dependent, this may be a compiler extension to allow it in initial values.

Comment: Are you sure that it comes from C code?

Comment: Voting to close since the code is clearly C++ not C.

Comment: Just edited to fix the tags. The OP is clearly writing C++ not C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is valid code because it is C++, not C. As [Kamil Cuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamil-cuk) points out, the code appears to come from [a C++ file](https://github.com/Digilent/openscope-mz/blob/master/LoopStats.cpp#L30) in the [openscope-mz](https://github.com/Digilent/openscope-mz) project. C++ allows initializers of this sort, while C does not except as implementation-dependent extensions.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is invalid C code without implementation defined extensions. Initialization of a static variable must be a constant expression. It is [specified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/constant_expression) what is a constant expression - the result of a function isn't on that list. The C standard allows an implementation to accept other forms of constant expressions, so with a implementation defined extension to accept such statements it could be a valid C code. Anyway I suspect it's not the case here.

The line

```
static  uint32_t    tSLoop              = ReadCoreTimer();
```

comes from [LoopStats.cpp](https://github.com/Digilent/openscope-mz/blob/master/LoopStats.cpp#L30) which is a C++ file.

Comment: Notwithstanding the fact the code fragment in the question likely comes from C++ rather than C, C 2018 6.6 10 says “An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions.” So, if the implementation accepts `ReadCoreTimer()` as a constant expression, this is not invalid C code, no constraint is violated, and no error or other diagnostic is required (assuming the code fragment is completed appropriately). This also means the statement “It is specified… what isn’t [a constant expression]” is false; by 6.6 10, the C standard clearly does not say what is not a constant expression.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: An expression that can't actually be constant in value obviously cannot be an implementation-defined additional form of constant expression.

Comment: @R..: Yes, it can. “Constant” has a limited meaning. I might define an array to have 5 elements in my source code, yet later change it to 6, so clearly it was not constant. I might define it to have `FOO` elements, where `FOO` appears nowhere in the source code but is passed as `-dFOO=number` on the command line. I might initialize a static string with the date and time its source file is compiled. I might initialize a static object with the time the program starts running, so it remains constant for the rest of program execution. A “constant” can be any value we pluck out of the universe.

Comment: @R..: In other words, the static object is initialized to the result of evaluating the expression. It is defined to be one single value, obtained in an implementation-defined way. It is not bound to some ongoing evaluation of the expression.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: If it's a function call that would necessarily return different values each time it's called (e.g. `static int x; return x++;`) then it clearly can't be part of a constant expression. WG14 does not practice the kind of precision needed to specify this formally, but it's clear by the meaning of the English words.

Comment: @eric: the c standard defines a constant expression as one that can be evaluated "during translation rather than runtime" (6.6/2). Despite the latitude provided by allowing implementations to accept other constants which can be evaluated during translation, I don't think that extends to the use of values which can only be evaluated at runtime (such as a hardware clock).

Comment: In other words, you can indeed pluck a constant out of the universe as you choose, but C requires that the constant stays plucked once the program has been translated. A subsequent execution of the same executable can't repluck.

Comment: I read "that can be evaluated during translation" as necessarily implying that the value can be determined at compile-time in such a way that the behavior follows the as-if rule, i.e. producing the same value as if the expression were evaluated according to the rules for evaluating it at runtime.

Comment: @rici: The C standard distinguishes translation and execution to permit there to be different translation and execution environments (5 1). If you require complete translation before a program starts and ban any run-time completion of it, then dynamically linked programs are not C, as address “constants” also included in clause 6.6, but their actual values may be unknown until linking occurs, which may be long after program start. Routines evaluated just as the program starts would be easier to squeeze in, as we simply define translation to end after this initialization, before calling `main`.

Comment: @R..: There is no “compile time” in the C standard, just translation and execution. And, as the dynamic linking issue shows, translation may continue to occur after execution begins. So I am positing an evaluation that is earlier than what we know must be allowed: Just before `main` is called.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Consider `static int x = foo(); int y = foo(); assert(x==y);` My argument is not about when it's evaluated, but the fact that a function where this assertion fails cannot possibly be a constant expression by virtue of the meaning of the word constant.

Comment: @R..: I see no reason to expect two different evaluations of expressions formed of identical text to return the same value. Each returns one value, which then becomes a constant for purposes of initialization. `__LINE__` has different values in different places, and `__TIME__` may have different values in different translation units. (Incidentally, clangs accepts `__TIME__[3]` as an initializer for a static object, but I have not worked through the standard yet to figure out if that is strictly conforming or an extension.)